# R doesn't recognize factor

Tags: r, kruskal-wallis

I'm going to do a Kruskal-Wallis test in R (testing whether there is a difference between dominance status in fish (five groups, measured from 1-5) and attacks by the fish) but it seems I have som problems with the factor. I import the dataset from Excel. R doesn't recognize the dominance status as a factor (returning FALSE when asked is.factor(dominance_status). When I import the dataset as a text file R doesn't recognize the first row as column names but instead writes V1 and V2 as the name of the columns.

I would be very thankful if somebody could please help me with this problem!

`Attack_data`
`Indvid Dominance_status Attacks`
`<chr> <dbl> <dbl>`
 `1 a1 3 0`
 `2 a2 3 0`
 `3 a3 4 0`

`# ... with 22 more rows`

`is.factor(Dominance_status)
[1] FALSE`

Comment: please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: If a column is coded as 1-5 then it will come in as numeric with most of the `read.*` functions unless you use colClasses. To make it a factor just use the `factor` function.

Comment: Please use `dput(head(dataset,20))` to provide sample data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers! I have now tried to add an example

Answer (score 2):

Because the Dominance_status is coded numerically, most read* functions will guess that it is a numeric class rather than a factor.

After reading in the data you could simply change the class to factor using as.factor() to force R to treat Dominance_status as a factor.

```r
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
             Indvid = c("a1", "a2", "a3"),
   Dominance_status = c(3, 3, 4),
            Attacks = c(0, 0, 0)
)

is.factor(df$Dominance_status)
#> [1] FALSE

df$Dominance_status <- as.factor(df$Dominance_status)

is.factor(df$Dominance_status)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Created on 2019-02-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Alternatively, you could use colClasses to specify that Dominance_status is a factor when you read in the data in the first place. Here is how you would do this using read.csv:

`read.csv(filename, colClasses = c(Dominance_status = "factor"))`